# Make JTextPane's Text Move Sideways Instead of a New Line

Tags: java, swing, jscrollpane, jtextpane

I am working with the JTextPane and am trying to make the text move sideways instead of a newline like the JTextField. I have tried searching and looking through the JTextPane's API but I haven't found anything useful. Could someone show me some type of method or process (that can be used in a main class) that could help me? Thanks you!

P.S.
I am aware of using the JScrollPane, but I would like to avoid that since I would like the JTextPane to look like a JTextField as much as possible.

Comment: If you want a `JTextField`, then use one. If you want a `JTextPane` you'll have to use `JScrollPane`, probably without word wrap and that is - apparently - hard. More info on it [here](http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2009/01/25/no-wrap-text-pane/).

Comment: I am using the JTextPane since I can insert images and text in the pane

Answer (score 2):

```
JTextPane textPane = new JTextPane();
JPanel noWrapPanel = new JPanel( new BorderLayout() );
noWrapPanel.add( textPane );
JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane( noWrapPanel );
```

[Solution Source](http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2009/01/25/no-wrap-text-pane/)

Plus:

```
JScrollPane.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_NEVER);
JScrollPane.setHorizontalScrollBarPolicy(HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_NEVER);
```

EDIT:

Solution **without** `JScrollPane`

```
import java.awt.Component;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JTextPane;
import javax.swing.plaf.ComponentUI;
import javax.swing.text.StyledDocument;

public class NonWrappingTextPane extends JTextPane {

    public NonWrappingTextPane() {
        super();
    }

    public NonWrappingTextPane(StyledDocument doc) {
        super(doc);
    }

    // Override getScrollableTracksViewportWidth
    // to preserve the full width of the text
    @Override
    public boolean getScrollableTracksViewportWidth() {
        Component parent = getParent();
        ComponentUI ui = this.getUI();

        return parent != null ? (ui.getPreferredSize(this).width <= parent.getSize().width) : true;
    }

    // Test method
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String content = "The plaque on the Apollo 11 Lunar Module\n"
                + "\"Eagle\" reads:\n\n"
                + "\"Here men from the planet Earth first\n"
                + "set foot upon the Moon, July, 1969 AD\n"
                + "We came in peace for all mankind.\"\n\n"
                + "It is signed by the astronauts and the\n"
                + "President of the United States.";
        JFrame f = new JFrame("Non-wrapping Text Pane Example");
        JPanel p = new JPanel();

        NonWrappingTextPane nwtp = new NonWrappingTextPane();
        nwtp.setText(content);

        p.add(nwtp);
        f.getContentPane().setLayout(new GridLayout(2, 1));
        f.getContentPane().add(p);

        f.setSize(300, 200);
        f.setVisible(true);

        f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    }
}
```

Comment: What about the automatic behaviour of JTextPane: wrapping lines by default?

Comment: @11684 Check the linked source, it's explained there.

Comment: @AdriánLópez My apologies, I thought it was a link to a full source on pastebin or something similar.

Comment: Thanks for the code, but could you please give a source I could put in a main class? Thanks!

Comment: @user1978786 You have it in the second source: http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/Swing-JFC/NonWrappingWrapTextPane.htm

Comment: I used that source and it was the same as just using a JScrollPane

Comment: @user1978786 You're right, sorry. Ok, you can just add it to another `JPanel` instead of a `JScrollPane`. Updated the answer with my modified version of the 2nd source. It's just a quick example though, you'll have to adapt it to your particular case, setting the panels's sizes, etc.